# How do you attach a wooden gate to fence with metal posts?

Tags: fence

I'm building a wood fence with metal posts. I'm using those clips that let you attach 2x4s horizontally to the metal posts. And then the boards go on top of that.

My question is how do you attach a gate? The only thing I can think of is a strap hinge. Are there other products out there that allow you to put a wood gate on a wood fence with metal posts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have numerous choices to deal with the gate hinge issue. For a round post you can clamp on this type of hinge and then bolt its flat plate to the gate:

[image]

Alternatively you could drill a horizontal hole through the metal post and install the bolt type hinge pin to be mated with the type of bolt on hinge strap in the second following picture:

[image]

[image]

A third option is to use the following U-bolt type hinge point mounted on the post. Then use a lag bolt hinge pin screwed into the gate framing:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use gate hinges that bolt through the metal pole.

Or alternately, bolt a 2x4 to the post on the gate side and then attach your gate hinges to that.